# Numbapro cuda python defining array in thread register in gpu

Tags: python, cuda, pycuda, numba, numba-pro

I know how to create a global device function inside Host using `np.array` or `np.zeros` or `np.empty(shape, dtype)` and then using `cuda.to_device` to copy.

Also, one can declare shared array as `cuda.shared.array(shape, dtype)`

But how to create an array of constant size in the register of a particular thread inside gpu function.

I tried `cuda.device_array` or `np.array` but nothing worked.

I simply want to do this inside a thread  -

```
x = array(CONSTANT, int32) # should make x for each thread
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbapro supports `numba.cuda.local.array(shape, type)` for defining thread local arrays.

As with CUDA C, whether than array is defined in local memory or register is a compiler decision based on usage patterns of the array. If the indexing pattern of the local array is statically defined and there is sufficient register space, the compiler will use registers to store the array. Otherwise it will be stored in local memory. See [this question and answer pair](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12167926/681865) for more information.